# How to ensure every user has latest Angular build

Tags: angular, service-worker, typescript2.0, angular-service-worker

I use a tracking software (intercom) to check which version of our clientside (Angular) app the user/client is on. From the data i can see several users being on previous versions. This causes a headache because different bug fixes and API requests are parts of different versions. Is there a way to have a uniform Angular version for everyone?
Each time a new app version is deployed everyone gets a notification to refresh their browser perhaps.

I tried to implement ServiceWorker approach but it is slightly wonky. It takes control of all the API requests and was slightly unpredictable.

Has anyone tried solving this issue?

Comment: Yes, you can make the app send its version as part of each HTTP request (using an interceptor adding a header, for example), and send back an error if they're not using the latest version, that would tell them to refresh.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks! Thats actually a good idea - Can you please elaborate a bit more. Wont it be slightly expensive operation to compare versions on each API request?
What i really need is something after each deployment.

Comment: No. Comparing two strings of a few characters is completely negligible compared to sending data over the network. Think the time it takes to go to your kitchen vs. the time it takes to travel to Mars.

Comment: @JBNizet :) - Angular side can be covered using Interceptors like you said. I am just wondering if that will be a significant work on the API level (.NET side)

Comment: I know nothing about .Net, but I'm pretty sure it has the same notion of an interceptor/filter that can be invoked for each request. A simple google search leads to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1